# Get email receipents onActivityResult

Tags: android, email, android-intent, onactivityresult

Is there a way to get the list of address to whom an email has been sent ?

**Explanation:**

The user choose email client.
The user write the mail and write the mail addresses to who he wants to send it.
The app say : email sent to x people (list of addresses).

I know onActivityResult doesn't work with email Intent but is there another way to get this information ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible unless you implement your own email client. Email clients doesn't share the date only way you share the data is by calling intent if users edits that it is inside email client which is not shared with anyone.

Comment: Damn... ican't do what i want then :( I need to implement sponsorship system by email, sms or facebook which send a code(random number) to each people you send the message. But if the user choose the email intent, no way to know how many users he sent the message, so the sponsorship system can't be right :( Any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

As I said before as far as I know it will be security breach on android and there is no way to do it unless you play around rules.